# что значит *m, = range(n+1) в питоне

Tags: python

можете объяснить код, а конкретно строку `*m, = range(n+1)`:

```
n, a, b, c, d = map(int, input().split())
*m, = range(n+1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Открываем `python` и проверяем руками что делает этот код:

```
$ python
@>>> n = 10
@>>> *m, = range(n+1)
@>>> m
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Видимо, `*m, = range(n+1)` это странный способ написать `m = list(range(n+1))`.

Удачи в самостоятельных проверках.

Comment: кстати такую запись `*m, = range(n+1)` впервые вижу, даже интересно стало, при том, что без запятой она не работает, как я понимаю это просто более короткая запись кода `m = list(range(n+1))`?

Comment: Висящая запятая говорит парсеру что это `tuple`. `*m` в сопоставлении получает список из всех элементов.

Comment: Скажем, у вас есть список и вы уверены что в нём один элемент. Как его вытащить? `item, = singular_list`.

Comment: Нотация перестаёт выглядеть странно если элементов несколько: `a, b = pair`.

Comment: Как разбить список на голову и длинный хвост? `head, *tail = long_list`.

Comment: Как разбить список на длинную голову и хвост? `*head, tail = long_list`.